# Can somebody please tell me what this decorator/adornment is in Eclipse for Synchronization/Incoming Mode?

Tags: eclipse, icons, synchronize

I have never seen this icon before with the pointer going up on top of the left arrow and cannot find in the eclipse doco.  What does it represent ?

[image]

Comment: I think the green part is actually an 'A' (probably for Abstract).

Comment: ah, thanks.  that makes sense.